# Add the same class to multiple elements from a Math.random function

Tags: jquery

Ho do I add the the same class to two elements.
Right now it adds two different classes to the elements with the class name "panzoom".

```
<div class="panzoom modell1"></div>
<div class="panzoom modell1"></div>



jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       animatemodels();
   });

   function animatemodels() {
       var classes = [ 'modell1', 'modell2', 'modell3', 'modell4', 'modell5', 'modell6', 'modell7'];

       jQuery(".panzoom").each(function(){
           jQuery(this).removeClass('modell1 ' + classes.join(' ')).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
       });

       setTimeout(animatemodels, 7000);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are getting a random class in each iteration of the each loop.

Instead just execute the random class generation once - there is no need to have the `each` loop, jQuery will do it for you

```js
var classes = ['modell1', 'modell2', 'modell3', 'modell4', 'modell5', 'modell6', 'modell7'];
var clazz = classes.join(' ');
jQuery(animatemodels);

function animatemodels() {
  jQuery(".panzoom").removeClass(clazz).addClass(clazz = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)]);
  setTimeout(animatemodels, 1000);
}
```

```css
.modell1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.modell2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.modell3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.modell4 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.modell5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.modell6 {
  background-color: grey;
}
.modell7 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panzoom modell1">1</div>
<div class="panzoom modell1">2</div>
```